# What is a good way to deal with multiple object types in the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have an abstract base class and two derived classes. The base class contains 6 properties which all can be maintained on a form.

The two derived classed both have 1 extra property. Those two properties can also be maintained on the same form.

In my form I have now code like this:

```
  btnSomething.visible = (myObject is DerivedA);
  pnlPanel.visible = !(myObject is DerivedA);

  if(myObject is DerivedA)
    myBindingSource.DataSource = myObject as DerivedA

  mySecondBindingSource = myObject;
```

I am not very happy with this approach, it smells. So my question is, what is a neat/good way to make this more OO? Because it is possibly that in the future DerivedC comes in...

I think this approach breaks the OCP principle (and probably other principles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polymorphism and inheritance here:

Define an interface

```
interface ICommonFeatures
{
    bool ContainsFoo {get;}
    //yak-yak
}
```

Then your derived classes implement it

```
class DerivedA: ICommonFeatures
{
    bool ContainsFoo {get {return true;}}
    //so-and-so
}
class DerivedB: ICommonFeatures
{
    bool ContainsFoo {get {return false;}}
    //this-and-that
}
```

And when you use it, you deal only with the interface

```
ICommonFeatures foo = new DerivedB();

btnSomething.visible = foo.ContainsFoo;
pnlPanel.visible = foo.Prop2;
myBindingSource.DataSource = foo.CurrentDataSource
```

Comment: I was thinking in this direction, but in your case, can I read `foo.Prop1` as `foo.ShowButtonSomething`? So basically, every GUI control that is dependent of the Derived class, you create a boolean property?

Comment: Yeah, but in the interface you should rather put logical load, not UI. So `ShowButtonSomething` => `ContainsFoo`. Then deeper in your logic you check that if the class contains foo then you would like to display a button. Such approach would keep the logic encapsulated in the class, and presentation will be separated from the model (which is always a good idea). Another thing is your GUI controls shall depend on the abstraction - interface or an abstract class if you'd prefer.

Comment: I think I get it, so in the `ICommonFeatures` I can have a property like `bool ContainsCompanyAddress` and in my form I set `txtCompanyAddress.visible = foo.ContainsCompanyAddress`?

Comment: How would you deal with databindings? I have different databindings for `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`

Answer (score 0):

A crazy idea would be make the UI extensible.
You could make a form implement a base form.

Then in the derived form class you would only insert the missing controls and behavior for the its model class.
In the derived model class or library you could have some sort binding to the correct form.

A good approach for this would be follow some MVP principles.

Hope it helps you somehow..

Comment: I did in fact an implementation like this, but in my solution I had different libraries implementing a set of interfaces and base classes, and each of the libraries could optionally derive from the main configuration form. Then in the main application I would show either the default form, or the custom one implemented by the library.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare an abstract boolean method/property for each control that need to behave according to the underlying type.

For instance

```
// to handle pnlPanel.visible = !(myObject is DerivedA);    
abstract bool SupportsPanel{get;}
```

As for your binding sources, I would also provide some virtual `BindingSource` and `SecondBindingSource` properties.

Maybe something like (purely an example)

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // All your exising class declaration here

    public virtual object BindingSource
    {
        get
        {
            // By default, a BaseClass is not valid as a binding source
            return null;
        }
    }

    public virtual object SecondBindingSource
    {
        get
        {
            // By default, a BaseClass is a valid Second Binding source
            return this;
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedA : BaseClass
{
    // All your exising class implementation here

    public override object BindingSource
    {
        get
        {
            // For DerivedA, the data sourse is itself.
            // other classes might have their own implementations.
            return this;
        }
    }

    // No need to override SecondBindingSource as the BaseClass one works as expected.

}
```

So, your code could stop caring about the object type and look like:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myObject.BindingSource;
mySecondBindingSource = myObject.SecondBindingSource;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide an (dummy) example of how to deal with bindingsources?

Comment: @Martijn I have updated my post for you. It is slightly different from what I had thought about at the begining, but the idea is the same: Only use your object as a `BaseClass` and encapsulate what is specific only inside the derived classes.